# how to get table data in json using linq and entityframework

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, linq

i have table with these fields sms,id,updtd_date. im trying get it in json but date value getting in different format. how to get updt_time field in string in json

o/p

```
/Date(1497309538000)/
```

req op

```
13-06-2017 04:48
```

code

```
 public ActionResult getSMS()
        {
            using (DBEntities dc = new DBEntities())
            {
                var data = dc.sms.OrderByDescending(a => a.id).ToList();
                return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: whatever date you got is json date format ? what are you looking for ?

Comment: try this answer this guy was facing similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/10566433/2745294

Comment: try this should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format/4540007#4540007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize your date manually:

```
public ActionResult getSMS()
{
    using (DBEntities dc = new DBEntities())
    {
        var data = dc.sms.OrderByDescending(a => a.id);
        return Json(data.Select(d => new { d.sms, d.id, updtd_date = d.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm") }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
}
```

Comment: getting compilation error.list<sm> does not contain definition for sms, id. fields of tables are not coming.

Comment: @dotnetcoder sorry, my fault. Please check edited version