# .Net datetime value Datatables.net bind error

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

*I wrote the codes short due to the maximum code text length.*

I'm trying use Datatables.
Datatables configure like this..

```
  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "scrollY": "500",

        "scrollX": true,
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/GetData/GetWeeklyData"
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "RecordDate"}
        ]
    });
```

But recordDate value format is  /Date(-62135596800000)/

[image]

GetWeeklyDate is;

```
  public List<DefaultLogs> GetWeeklyData()
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(_appSettings.MongoClient);
            var filter = Builders<DefaultLogs>.Filter;
            var database = client.GetDatabase(_appSettings.MongoDbName);
            var collection = database.GetCollection<DefaultLogs>(_appSettings.CollFilteredLogs);

            var endDate = DateTime.Now;
            var startDate = endDate.AddDays(-7);

            var query = filter.Gte(x => x.RecordDate, new BsonDateTime(startDate)) & filter.Lte(x => x.RecordDate, new BsonDateTime(endDate));

            var result = collection.Find(query).ToList();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Data model;

```
  public class DefaultLogs
{
  
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
    
}
```

Datetime value is correct in C# side.I think I need to send it as String.How can I?

Comment: `/Date(62135596800000)/` looks like the default DateTime serialisation of ASP.Net. What version are you using?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: You should probably configure Json.Net to handle JSON (de)serialization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC Controller.Json DateTime Serialization vs NewtonSoft Json DateTime Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527001/asp-net-mvc-controller-json-datetime-serialization-vs-newtonsoft-json-datetime-s)

Comment: Unfortunately, Datatables did not accept Newtonsoft serialization.

Comment: I looped the list and converted the RecordDate field to String