# MVC4 Action returning JsonResult without null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a action which returns an JsonResult for an object of a particular class. I have decorated the properties of this class with some attrib to avoid null fields. Class definition is:

```
    private class GanttEvent
    {
        public String name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public String desc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<GanttValue> values { get; set; }
    }
```

And in my Action i use an object

```
    var res = new List<GanttEvent>();
```

which I return using:

```
    return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Unfortunatelly, I'm still receiving null values at output:

```
    [{"name":"1.1 PREVIOS AL INICIO ","desc":null,"values":null},{"name":"F04-PGA-S10","desc":"Acta preconstrucción","values":null},{"name":"F37-PGA-S10","desc":"Plan de inversión del anticipo","values":null},{"name":"F09-PGA-S10","desc":"Acta de vecindad","values":null},{"name":"F05-PGA-S10","desc":"Acta de inicio","values":null},{"name":"F01-PGA-S10","desc":"Desembolso de anticipo","values":null}]
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated by Brad Christie, MVC4 stills uses JavaScriptSerializer, so in order to get your object serialized by Json.Net, you will have to perform several steps.

First, inherit a new class JsonNetResult from JsonResult as follows (based on  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883204/change-default-json-serializer-used-in-asp-mvc3)):

```
public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{
    public JsonNetResult()
    {
        this.ContentType = "application/json";
    }

    public JsonNetResult(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior jsonRequestBehavior)
    {
        this.ContentEncoding = contentEncoding;
        this.ContentType = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentType) ? contentType : "application/json";
        this.Data = data;
        this.JsonRequestBehavior = jsonRequestBehavior;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType) ? ContentType : "application/json";

        if (ContentEncoding != null)
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;

        if (Data == null)
            return;

        // If you need special handling, you can call another form of SerializeObject below
        var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Formatting.None);
        response.Write(serializedObject);
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, override the Json method to use the new class:

```
protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
    return new JsonNetResult(data, contentType, contentEncoding, behavior);
}
```

Comment: Don't know if this answer is still relevant, but I needed something like this, and did a c/p of your code. Unfortunately, it didn't work as expected, but I edited your JsonNetResult class slightly:                                               var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings{ NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore});                                      ...and now it works perfectly. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`Controller.Json`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470587%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) uses the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) not the [Newtonsoft Json library](https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json) (which is where the [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonPropertyAttribute.cs) originates from).

You'll either need to use the Newtonsoft library library and return the serialized result that way, or you continue calling `Json` and write a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) that will ignore nulls.

Comment: Thanks, I was suspicious about that, and you confirmed my thoughs. In the end, Json.Net is the default serializer, but just for **WebAPI**, not for regular MVC site.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to see what happens if you just serialize one GanttEvent object to JSON. Also check your call to Json is appropriate.