# How to ignore property if it is null while creating JSON response?

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq

I have 1 class like below:

```
public class Tables
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] Columns { get; set; }
    }

string[] selectedTables = { "Table1", "Table2"};
using (var conection = new SqlConnection("MyconnectionString"))
{
    connection.Open();

    var tables = (
        from table in connection.GetSchema("Tables").AsEnumerable()
        let name = (string)table["TABLE_NAME"]
        where selectedTables.Contains(name)
        let catalog = (string)table["TABLE_CATALOG"]
        let schema = (string)table["TABLE_SCHEMA"]
        select new Tables // this should really be called Table
        {
            Name = name,
            Columns = (
                from column in connection.GetSchema("Columns", new [] { catalog, schema, name }).AsEnumerable()
                select (string)column["COLUMN_NAME"]).ToArray()
        }).ToList();

    return tables;
}
```

Here  i am creating response to return data to service:

```
     var response = tables.
                      Select
                   (
                        t => new
                          {
                            id = t.Id,
                            tables = t.Tables
                            .Select
                            (
                              x => new
                               {
                                   name = x.Name,
                                   columns = x.Columns 
                               }
                             ).ToList()
                          }
                    ).ToList();

  return Json(response);
```

Below is my JSON:

[image: Output]

Now when generating columns data for each tables if **columns is null** for suppose **Table1** then **I don't want this columns field to be present
in my JSON**.

Is this possible because I follow this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987375/remove-the-null-property-from-object) in which it is written that it is not possible.

**Update**: I am using **asp.net mvc** so I am doing like this to create [json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx) - is that possible?

```
return Json(response);
```

This is not duplicate question as I am using JSON class of MVC to generate JSON result.

Comment: Where is the code that generates the Json string? Without it, the rest isn't relevant. In fact, you could remove all the database related code and use a test object and the serialization code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have updated my question to include the code which generate json response.i am usin JsonConvert.SerializeObject to create json response

Comment: @Learning Specific property or all null properties ?

Comment: @OrelEraki:Suppose if i want to ignore specific property then is it possible??

Comment: “What are you using to generate the JSON?” – “I’m using JSON.NET!” – *solution for JSON.NET* – “No wait, I actually lied. You are so wrong about it, this is not a duplicate!!!” – Seriously? Anyway, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20974811/216074) and also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13294211/216074)… it’s still a duplicate.

Comment: @poke Sorry for the inconvinience actually i havent specified asp.net mvc tag and JsonConvert.SerializeObject is very common that is why i posted JsonConvert.SerializeObject.If i would have posted Json then some users would have confused that what is json as it is a class in asp.net mvc for creating json response

Answer (score 5):

You can tell the Json serializer to ignore empty properties like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                            });
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  The OP should also look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819640/ignoring-null-fields-in-json-net   This might help.

Comment: Ok this works but suppose if i am not using JsonConvert.SerializeObject object then how it is possible to do this??

Comment: I have upvoted your answer because it works with jsonConvert.SerializeObject