# Why does JsonResult return altered Json (with \" instead of ")?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I have the following Action written in a WebApi Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var item = new Item();
        item.GenerateData();

        var jsonMediaTypeFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
            {
                UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true
            };


        var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

        var serializedData = jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonMediaTypeFormatter, item);

        var jsonResult = new JsonResult
        {
            ContentType = "application/json",
            Data = serializedData,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
        };

        return jsonResult;
    }
```

The line:
   var serializedData = jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonMediaTypeFormatter, item);

serializes data into Json hence I have:

```
{"Class":{"Valid":{"From":"\/Date(1363302000000+0100)\/","To":"\/Date(43017433200000+0100)\/"},"Code":3,"Id":3,"Name":"Class3"},
```

and so on.. (not a full Json)

but the Json returned by JsonResult is different:

```
{"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":"application\/json","Data":"{\"Class\":{\"Valid\":{\"From\":\"\\\/Date(1363302000000+0100)\\\/\",\"To\":\"\\\/Date(43017433200000+0100)\\\/\"},\"Code\":3,\"Id\":3,\"Name\":\"Class3\"},
```

Notice *\"* in the text.
Why it is so? How to change it? I cannot figure it out..

**EDIT** *JsonSerializer* JsonSerializer is my helper class that serializes data to Json using DataContractJsonSerializer its code is following:

```
public class JsonSerializer
{
    public string Serialize<T>(MediaTypeFormatter formatter, T value)
    {
        // Create a dummy HTTP Content.
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        var content = new StreamContent(stream);

        // Serialize the object.
        formatter.WriteToStreamAsync(typeof(T), value, stream, content, null).Wait();

        // Read the serialized string.
        stream.Position = 0;
        return content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

What I would like to have is the result of its execution - and without being changed - returned to the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JsonResult` already serializes whatever you put inside `Data` to JSON.

Your code manually serializes to JSON before setting `Data`, which results in the output containing a double-serialized object (`item` is first manually serialized to a JSON string, then the string is *again* serialized using JSON rules -- it is this second serialization that is escaping your quotes).

While technically we cannot rule out the possibility that the double serialization is done on purpose, most likely what you should be doing is

```
var jsonResult = new JsonResult
    {
        ContentType = "application/json",
        Data = item,
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
    };
```

If you don't want to serialize twice but need to serialize manually then use `ContentResult` instead:

```
return new ContentResult
       {
           ContentType = "application/json",
           Content = serializedData,
       };
```

Comment: I forgot to add. I need to serialize data with DataContractJsonSerializer how to have it serialized with it then?

Comment: Nice, thanks but I am still not quite satisfied with the result (look at the edited question)

Comment: @lukasz.pek: What exactly is `JsonSerializer`?

Answer (score 0):

The double-quotes are escaped.  This is both intended and desired behavior - it keeps strings (like the string which holds the JSON data) from being closed early.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the built-in `Json()` method, which builds the result object for you?

```
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var item = new Item();
    item.GenerateData();

    return Json(item);
}
```

If you need detailed control of how the serialization is done, you can [create your own version of the `JsonResult` class and override `Execute()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6884503/38055). That post also suggests creating a base class for your controllers which override the `Json()` method, but I'd rather create an extension method on `Controller` - for one thing, this doesn't put any requirements on your controllers in terms of base classes, and for another it doesn't hide the default behavior if you should need it:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
     public static JsonResult DataContractJson(this Controller ctrl, object data) {
         return new DataContractJsonResult { Data = data };
     }
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404233/38055) (to the same question as the one above) seems to accomplish exactly what you're doing - choosing a JSON serializer that can handle the data contract attributes.